# Accessing local variables in the calling context

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In my code, i have several methods using the following pattern

```
def my_method only: [], ignore: []
  something('textvalue') if (only.empty? && ignore.empty?) || (only.any? && only.include?('textvalue')) || (ignore.any? && !ignore.include?('textvalue'))
end
```

In other word, i can choose to filter the results either by specifying `only` or `ignore`, depending on which one is more convenient in the context.

I would like a way to declare a helper `want` that access the `only`and `ignore` local parameters without having to specify them each time, the result would ideally look like this:

```
def my_method only: [], ignore: []
  something('textvalue') if want('textvalue')
end
```

This helper would be used in several different methods, classes, etc. It would somehow check the local variables at the calling point, validate that `only` and `ignore` exists, and then check if the parameter is wanted or not.

Is it possible to access the calling stack and look at the local variables there?

Comment: `(only.any? && only.include?('textvalue'))` can be simplified to `only.include?('textvalue')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gem `binding_of_caller` which can do this.  Install the gem and then do

```
require 'binding_of_caller'

def my_method only: [], ignore: []
  something('textvalue') if want('textvalue')
end

def want(value)
  only = binding.of_caller(1).local_variable_get(:only)
  ignore = binding.of_caller(1).local_variable_get(:ignore)
  (only.empty? && ignore.empty?) || (only.any? && only.include?(value)) || (ignore.any? && !ignore.include?(value))
end
```

But this is a bad thing to do as it creates very high coupling.  It's really not good design.  If you want to do this for experimentation and playing around, fair enough, but don't do it in production.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, but I don't understand why you don't seems to be recommending it. Using want('textvalue', only: only, ignore: ignore) everywhere is still coupling want with `only` and `ignore`, but is more verbose. Hardly a better choice as far as I can see. What would you propose?

Comment: @JérômeTremblay You still have to define your methods with the correct signature, otherwise want will fail. I would recommend metaprogramming instead, or keyword arguments.

Comment: It's a hidden coupling... `want` is dependent on local variables in the calling method but it's not clear when examining the calling method. @andrly-baran answer suffers from the same issue but I actually prefer his answer as you don't need an external gem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ruby method definition to do this

```
def my_method val, only: [], ignore: [], want: ->(val) { ((only.empty? && ignore.empty?) || (only.any? && only.include?(val))) }
 something(val) if want.call(val)
end

my_method 'value', only: ['value2']
=> false
```

Comment: Think your method call would return `nil` as  `want` would be `false` in this scenario. Just for clarification's sake, is that what you were after here?

Comment: This is a very excellent answer!  Something to remember for the future. Your're missing the "include" part of the original queston, though.

Answer (score 2):

In circumstances such as this, couldn't you just pass the args to `want`?

```
def my_method only: [], ignore: []
  something('textvalue') if want?('textvalue', only, ignore)
end

def want?(string, only, ignore)
  (only.empty? && ignore.empty?) || (only.any? && only.include?(string)) || (ignore.any? && !ignore.include?(string))
end
```

Doesn't seem to be any need for it to be more complex than that?

That is a *lot* simpler to manage and for others to deal with going forward - which I'd consider far more important than avoiding passing a couple of args to a method.

Comment: That is the solution i used in the end. While I wanted to avoid it because it's more verbose, it is indeed vastly simpler, and `binding_of_caller` has some quirks that makes it a pretty cool hack but solid alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the update @JérômeTremblay - when you actually break it down, this is actually shorter than either other option here. I'd always argue for simplicity over a few extra args being passed around, regardless of how many times you're calling this. You'll thank yourself and others will do the same when revisiting the code a while down the line.